# Struts2 type conversion Checkboxlist

Tags: struts2, checkboxlist

i have a index.jsp home page which has following checkboxlist to select the favorite fruit:

```
friuts that i like : <s:checkboxlist name="myFruits" list="{'apple','mango','orange'}"/>
```

in the actionssupport file, i have used the 'myFruits' String type. :

```
public class Action1 extends ActionSupport 
{
    String myFruits;
     public String getMyFruits() {
        return myFruits;
    }

    public void setMyFruits(String myFruits) {
        this.myFruits = myFruits;
    }

public String execute()
    {   

        return "success";
    }

}
```

And the `results.jsp` which reads the selected values :

```
 my favorite fruit is:<br>
  <s:property value="myFruits"/>
```

the output  comes up correctly.

```
my favorite fruit is:
apple, mango
```

But i am not able to understand how the multiple values selected for example apple and mango are getting stored in valuestack with String `myFruit` type. Shouldn't this be a `List` or an array?

Why the above code works fine with just a String type to hold multiple String names?

Comment: If it is string then it doesn't hold multiple values. It is one string where values are separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not able to understand how the multiple values selected for example `apple` and `mango` are getting stored in valuestack with String `myFruit` type. Shouldn't this be a `List` or an array?

You have a string property with the name `myFruits` and parameters with the same name. Struts is doing the best to populate that property, and if the parameter has multiple values but a property is a single string type, they could be converted as string with values separated by comma.

On the other hand if you have an array or list property type, the values will be set as array or list.

Comment: The type is determined by the default type converter, if it can find suitable setter for the property.